# Change colspan of cells with identical content, so they appear to be merged

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have got a table with redundant data in cells. [Left table]

I need to join them into one cell. [Right table]

[image: Illustration]

Structure of table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">Value1:</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">B</td>
    <td class="green">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">Value2:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">C</td>
    <td class="green">C</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">D</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am able to hide redundant cell, but I need to set colspan somehow.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var all = $('.green');
var seen = {};
all.each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt]) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
        seen[txt] = true;
    }
});


});
```

Comment: You are aware your table will crash and burninate when those 4 values are not unique right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var all = $('.green');
  var first;
  var prev = undefined;
  var colspan = 1;

  var setColspan = function() {
    first.attr('colspan', colspan);
    colspan = 1;
  }

  all.each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (prev === txt) {
      colspan += 1;
      $(this).remove();
    } else {
      // doesnt match, set colspan on first and reset colspan counter
      if (colspan > 1) {
        setColspan();
      }
      first = $(this);
      prev = txt;
    }
  });

  if (colspan > 1) {
    setColspan();
  }

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">Value1:</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">B</td>
    <td class="green">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">Value2:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">C</td>
    <td class="green">C</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">D</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Think it does what you want, checks for consecutive blocks of matching column values, if it finds a match, it removes it, when it doesnt find a match and colspan is large enough it sets the colspan on the first in the list and then resets.  it doesnt work if you have consecutive values that span end of one row and into the beginning of the next.  would want to do it row by row if that is the case

updated above with edge case if last set of columns are consecutive as well. it wouldnt set the colspan in that case then.

Comment: Your logic will not work when `text in last td of any row is same as text in first td of next row`.

Answer (score 2):

[Answer from @Kevin Nacios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16764474/9695286) is almost perfect but it will not work when `text in last td of any row is same as text in first td of next row`.

Try like below. Explanation is in comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // loop over each tr
  $('tr').each((index, tr) => {

    // get first td
    let td = $(tr).find('td').eq(0);
    // set colspan value
    let colspan = 1;

    // if td exist then proceed
    while (td.length) {
      // find next td
      let next = td.next();

      // if current td and next td has same text then remove next td
      if (td.text().trim().length > 0 && td.text().trim() == next.text().trim()) {
        // remove next td
        next.remove();
        // increase colspan
        colspan++;
        // set colspan
        td.attr('colspan', colspan);
      } else {
        // reset colspan
        colspan = 1;
        // set next as current td
        td = next;
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">Value1:</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td class="green">A</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">B</td>
    <td class="green">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">B</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">C</td>
    <td class="green">C</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="green">D</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the colspan by,

```
var cell=$([selector]);
cell.attr('colspan',N);
```

and then delete the following siblings

```
var sib=cell.next();
for(var i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  if(sib.length==0)break; 
  var toBeRemoved=sib;
  sib=sib.next(); 
  toBeRemoved.remove();
}
```