# display or read colspan value

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I created a table contain the colspan and rowspan. Then I would like to get or read these colspan and rowspan value. I'm doing this because I want to use it for xml generation. I need this value. I play around with this code to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayResult()
{
document.getElementById("myHeader1").colSpan="2";
}
function displayColSpan()
{
var te;
document.getElementById("myHeader1").colSpan=te;
alert(te);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th id="myHeader1">Month</th>
    <th id="myHeader2">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$10.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$80.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Change colSpan for the first cell</button>
<button type="button" onclick="displayColSpan()">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: And where, and how, does that script not work? What goes wrong with it, and in which browsers?

Comment: What does `displaResult()` suppose to do?

Comment: Your `displayColSpan()` function declares the variable `te` but _doesn't assign it a value_ before using it to set the `.colSpan` property of your table cell. In practice I think setting `.colSpan = undefined` gives the same effect as setting it to `1`. (I would expect the `alert(te)` statement to show `undefined`?)

Comment: DavidThomas : The code work. I just want to read/get the colSpan value. I tried in the displayColSpan() function.

alkid : displayResult is to see the result after Im using aplly the colspan to the header. example before i edited is here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_th_colspan

nnnnnn : I want to read/get the value of colSpan.. Not set the value. This code just to play around to trying to get what I want..

Comment: _"I want to read/get the value of colSpan.. Not set the value."_ - OK, but your current code as shown _sets_ the value. When you say `a = b` the thing on the left of the `=` is set to the value on the right. (So your code `document.getElementById("myHeader1").colSpan=te` sets the `.colSpan` to be equal to whatever `te` is (`undefined`).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion with your code.

This:

```
document.getElementById("myHeader1").colSpan=te;
```

Changes the colspan value of myHeader1 to `var te`, which is undefined. Instead you should do:

```
te = document.getElementById("myHeader1").colSpan
```

now `te` is the colspan value of myHeader1.

If you want to get the value, that is 'month':

```
te = document.getElementById("myHeader1").innerHTML
```

Now te has the value of 'month'!

Hope this helps!

Comment: @alKid, I'm using var te to test to get the value of colSpan. Then to show it to me in the dialog. I'm not setting it. Not the value of 'month', but the row colSpan. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it

Comment: yeahh the second one. Thanks @alKid! It just simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using was copied from this site: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_th_colspan Isn't it?

Good, then you must have noticed that what they are doing there? They are simply changing the properties of the columns and their span, what we can say in css might be padding.

You want to get the value of the span? I never tried javascript for this, I have always used CSS.

But still, go through this page: [Calculate and set colspan value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764404/calculate-and-set-colspan-value-dynamically)

He showed a well developed code, you can also try out getting the values from element such as:

```
var val=document.getElementById("idofel").style.backgroundColor;
```

To get the background-color, you can try such other values for this table too. Obviously not background-color, but the necessary ones. And then write them in XML!

Comment: yes on that link. But I manipulated it to play around. I want to get the colSpan value. Are you sure we can get it using css? Can you show it how? thanks!

Comment: No using CSS, but using CSS styles! in JavaScript, just like I did for `backgroundColor`