# Set colspan value dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a table with dynamic data in cells.

| SL | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | B |
| 2 | C | D | D |

I need to join cells with identical content into one cell, like below.

```
----------------------------------
| SL | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3|
-----------------------------------
| 1  |         A         |    B   |
-----------------------------------
| 2  |    C    |         D        |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the html table structure? How it's generated? Do you want to create a new table with the merged, or modify the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. Explanation is in comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // loop over each tr
  $('tr').each((index, tr) => {

    // get first td
    let td = $(tr).find('td').eq(0);
    // set colspan value
    let colspan = 1;

    // if td exist then proceed
    while (td.length) {
      // find next td
      let next = td.next();

      // if current td and next td has same text then remove next td
      if (td.text().trim() == next.text().trim()) {
        // remove next td
        next.remove();
        // increase colspan
        colspan++;
        // set colspan
        td.attr('colspan', colspan);
      } else {
        // reset colspan
        colspan = 1;
        // set next as current td
        td = next;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.s-table th,
.s-table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-table-container">
  <table class="s-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>SL</th>
        <th>Value 1</th>
        <th>Value 2</th>
        <th>Value 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to put a border around the table, and it doesn't seem to be applying the colspan. It seems to only remove the next element, except when there are 3 identical values in a row, then it applies the colspan on the first 2.

Comment: There was a minor mistake in `else` condition. I need to reset `colspan = 1`. Updated code and you can test it is working as expected. Added css just to verify changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this.

I basically take each td, and compare the text with the next td and merge them if they match.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table tbody tr td").each(function() {
    var n1 = $(this).text();
    var t = $(this).nextUntil("td:not(:contains(" + n1 + "))");
    var n3 = t.length || 0;
    $(this).attr("colspan", n3 + 1);
    t.remove();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table tbody tr td").each(function() {
    var n1 = $(this).text();
    var t = $(this).nextUntil("td:not(:contains(" + n1 + "))");
    var n3 = t.length || 0;
    $(this).attr("colspan", n3 + 1);
    t.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SL</th>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
      <th>Value 3</th>
      <th>Value 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there's the same value in 3 columns in a row. Example if Value1, Value2 and value2 all are "E".

Comment: @Scratte was not a requirement from the op, but have updated the code.

Comment: Not sure if you're willing to, but this post looks like a duplicate of [Change colspan of cells with identical content, so they appear to be merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764404/change-colspan-of-cells-with-identical-content-so-they-appear-to-be-merged). If you reopen this, you'd be able to use your gold tag to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Your logic may break in case if there is possibility that `td` have text which have multiple letters. For ex. suppose first `td` has `A` and second `td` has `AB` then it will get merged. Though this is totally depend on OP's requirement.

Comment: @Scratte I know how my rep works and what i can, If you believe its a duplicate. Just flag the question with it.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry for the inconvenience.